# WildFly Maven Plugin - Setting Blank Context Root

Tags: maven, wildfly

I am using the Maven WildFly plugin and have the following in my `pom.xml` (version is `2.0.1.Final` and path points to a local WildFly `8.2.1.Final` server).

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jboss-home>${wildfly.path}</jboss-home>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The application is getting deployed as `localhost:8080/myArtifactId-myVersion` which is expected as the default behavior is to use the WAR name. However, I want to change the context root so that the application is accessible via `localhost:8080/` (i.e. I want a blank context root).

**Method 1: Change the Pom Configuration**

I can change the `finalName` build setting in my `pom.xml` as follows.

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>newContextRoot</finalName>
</build>
```

This correctly updates the url to `localhost:8080/newContextRoot`. I then tried to change it to be a blank value.

```xml
<build>
    <finalName></finalName>
</build>
```

However, this results in a `Value must not be empty` error in my IDE and when I try to build it fails, saying `Error assembling WAR: A zip file cannot include itself`.

**Method 2: Change Plugin Configuration**

Probably the better solution is to change the configuration of the Maven WildFly plugin itself. Under the `<configuration>` section, I can add the following.

```xml
<name>anotherContextRoot.war</name>
```

This correctly changes the url to `localhost:8080/anotherContextRoot`. So then I tried again to create a blank name as in the following.

```xml
<name>.war</name>
```

However, this results in an `IllegalArgumentException: Empty name segment is not allowed for module`.

**Question**

Does anyone know the appropriate way to make the context root blank? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out. You do not need to do anything except add a `jboss-web.xml` file into the `WEB-INF` directory as follows.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <default-encoding>UTF-8</default-encoding>
</jboss-web>
```

This sets the context root and overrides what the plugin was doing.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your war with the name `ROOT.war` and deploy it, WildFly will configure it as root application.